# Validate e-mail field in Rails 4 with Judge gem. Cross browser problems

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have simple registration form. I have set up multiple validations. All of them work except 
email format validation.

In model:

```
 validates :name,:region, :age, :height,:phone_number,:weight, :email,
            :description,
            :presence => {:message => "empty value found"}

validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
```

View:

```
<%= f.email_field :email,:placeholder=> "E-pasts *", :validate => true%>
```

Script:

```
function validate() {
    judge.validate(document.getElementById('advertisement_email'), {
      valid: function(element) {
        element.style.border = '1px solid green';
      },
      invalid: function(element, messages) {
        element.style.border = '1px solid red';
        alert(messages.join(','));
      }
    });
}
```

**Validation is triggered from submit button.**

```
  <div class="clickable8 ">
              <%= link_to "PIEVIENOT", "#", :onclick => "validate()" %>
                    <span style="padding-left:132px;">PIEVIENOT</span>
   </div>
```

**Problems:**

1) In Chrome validation passes even if nothing is in email field.

2) In Firefox validation works in the same moment when I am writting in that field.

It passes with valid e-mail and fails with invalid e-mail. As I need.

Question: **How can I trigger validation with that click button in both browsers ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Javascript console for errors. Rails regex are not always compatible with Javascript regex, and it can change among browsers.